# Specify max width for all select in my form

Tags: jquery, css, select

I have a form with several selects (dropdown lists).

I want all of them to have max-width:300px, I tried this, but not working:

```
$(#myform 'select').css(width, '300px');
```

Comment: Why are you using javascript to add CSS instead of just using CSS?

Comment: Why are you using `width` when you want `max-width`?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong

```
$('#myform select').css(width, '300px');
```

but in any case you would do this with pure CSS

```
#myform select{
    width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery it should be:

```
$('#myform select').css('max-width', '300px');
```

And pure CSS:

```
#myform select{
    max-width:300px;
}
```

Comment: `max-width` should be in quotes :)